# How to Add Bullet Points in aspx page while reading a txt file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, richtextbox, bulletedlist

What I am wanting to do is read a file from a .txt file and when the text of the .txt file shows up in the textbox it should be formatted into bulleted form (every line starts with a bullet point) rather than simple lines.

Here is how I am reading the file from the server:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    string txt = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/TextFile1.txt"));    
    txtBox1.Text = txt;    
} 


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
<head runat="server">    
</head>    
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
        <div>    
        <asp:button id="btn1" runat="server" text="Read" onclick="btn_Click" /><br /><br />    
            Results:<br />     
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="250px" width="350px">    
            </asp:TextBox>    
            </div>    
    </form>     
</body>     
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve it:

1. Use [BulletedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist?view=netframework-4.8) instead.
2. [Read line by line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time) from your `TextFile1.txt` file then append `\u2022` text before each line.

Answer (score 0):

use `\u2022`

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{ 
string[] txt  = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/TextFile1.txt")); 
foreach (string line in txt )
{
txtBox1.Text += "\u2022 '" + line + "'\t\n";
}
}
```

Comment: ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/TextFile1.txt")); works for me instead of ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/TextFile1.txt"));

Comment: @AbdulQayyum  Happy to help :) consider marking it as answer if it a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
 string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.UTF8);
 string text = string.Empty; // or use StringBuilder;
 foreach (string s in readText)
 {
     text += $"\u2022 {s}" + System.Environment.NewLine;
 }

 txtBox1.Text = text;
```